# Trying to use JS to run redirects on my page. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

My page is supposed to redirect from the root page on my website to one of two different subpages, linked via buttons on the root page. The buttons don't work.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <input type="button" class="button" value="My GitHub portfolio" onclick="page1();">
      <br>
      <input type="button" class="button" value="Start Page" onclick="page2();">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var pageto;

function page1(){
    var pageto = 1;
    reload();
};

function page2(){
    var pageto = 2;
    reload();
};

function reload(){
    if (pageto == 1){
        location.href('personal-website');
    }
    else if (pageto == 2){
        location.href('start-gp');
    };
};
```

Comment: Could you expand on *"buttons don't work"*? Any errors in the console? href isn't a method, for one thing; see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is, that you redeclare the `pageto` variable inside `page1` and `page2`, so the `reload` function can't access it.

You can remove the `var` keyword before the assignment, to set the global one (not recommended):

```js
var pageto;
function page1(){
    pageto = 1;
    reload();
};

function page2(){
    pageto = 2;
    reload();
};
```

Or, pass it as an argument to `reload`. That way you can avoid creating unnecessary variables:

```js
function page1(){
    reload(1);
};

function page2(){
    reload(2);
};
function reload(pageto){
  //Contents of reload function
};
```

---

The second problem is the the `location.href` property contains the URL of the page, and it is not a function. You can redirect the page by assigning the new URL to it:

```js
function reload(){
    if (pageto == 1){
        location.href='personal-website';
    }
    else if (pageto == 2){
        location.href='start-gp';
    };
};
```

Alternatively, you can use the `window.open` method, to redirect the browser:

```js
function reload(){
    if (pageto == 1){
        window.open('personal-website','_self');
    }
    else if (pageto == 2){
        window.open('start-gp','_self');
    };
};
```

Or the similar `location.replace`:

```js
function reload(){
    if (pageto == 1){
        location.replace('personal-website','_self');
    }
    else if (pageto == 2){
        location.replace('start-gp','_self');
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function redirect(el){
    location.href = el.getAttribute("data-url");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="button" value="My GitHub portfolio" onclick="redirect(this)" data-url="personal-website">
<br>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Start Page" onclick="redirect(this)" data-url="start-gp">
```